# Error occurs while deploying cutom timer job SP 2010

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, timer-jobs

I am creating timer job in which the list item is added every 5 minutes.

My class file which inherits `SPJobDefinition` is :

```
public class MyTimerJob : SPJobDefinition
{
    public MyTimerJob() : base() { }

    public MyTimerJob(SPWebApplication webApp)
            : base("MyTimerJob", webApp, null, SPJobLockType.None)
    {
        this.Title = "MyCustomTimerJob";
    }
    public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
    {
        SPSite site = new SPSite("http://bipc11:1234/sites/publishing1");
        SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
        SPList list = web.Lists["Sample Tasks"];
        SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
        item["Title"] = "Added Programmatically";
        item.Update();
    }

}
```

Feature Event Receiver is as below:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPSite site = new SPSite("http://bipc11:1234/sites/publishing1");
    foreach (SPJobDefinition job in site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions)
    {
        if(job.Name.Equals("MyTimerJob"))
            job.Delete();


        MyTimerJob timerJob = new MyTimerJob(site.WebApplication);
        SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
        schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
        schedule.Interval = 5;
        timerJob.Schedule = schedule;
        timerJob.Update();
    }
}

public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{   
      SPSite site = new SPSite("http://bipc11:1234/sites/publishing1");
      foreach (SPJobDefinition job in site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions)
      {
          if (job.Name.Equals("MyTimerJob"))
              job.Delete();
      }
}
```

I the scope of the feature is `Site Collection` level.

The code is built successfully but when I deploy the solution I am getting the error :

`Error  1   Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': An object of the type TimerJob10092013.MyTimerJob named "MyTimerJob" already exists under the parent Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication named "SharePoint - 1234".  Rename your object or delete the existing object.`

I uninstalled the feature from power shell but still I am getting the error?

What am I missing ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be it

```
foreach (SPJobDefinition job in site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions)
{
    if(job.Name.Equals("MyTimerJob"))
        job.Delete();


    MyTimerJob timerJob = new MyTimerJob(site.WebApplication);
    SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
    schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
    schedule.Interval = 5;
    timerJob.Schedule = schedule;
    timerJob.Update();
}
```

should be

```
foreach (SPJobDefinition job in site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions)
{
    if(job.Name.Equals("MyTimerJob"))
        job.Delete();
}

MyTimerJob timerJob = new MyTimerJob(site.WebApplication);
SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
schedule.Interval = 5;
timerJob.Schedule = schedule;
timerJob.Update();
```

you're trying to add the exact same timer for every job definition in the web app ;)

Comment: Aaah, silly mistake.. Thank you very much sir, it worked perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

In looking at my code, compared to yours, the biggest difference i see is that the this.Title in the timer is different from the title in the declaration. Consider doing the following instead

```
public MyTimerJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication webApp)
            : base(jobName, webApp, null, SPJobLockType.None)
{
    this.Title = jobName;
}
```

and then in the feature

```
MyTimerJob timerJob = new MyTimerJob("MyTimerJob", site.WebApplication);
```

I find this design helps guarantee the naming will be the same each time.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, I made the changes as per your suggestion but still I am getting same error.

Comment: My bad, didn't see this before... code doens't fly in this comment, will make another answer

Comment: I did some steps to make sure that there is no solution available.
First run powershell command i.e. `Get-SPFeature > c:\features.txt`. Then, found the feature that was available in the list, got GUID and run the below command,
i.e. `Uninstall-SPFeature -Identity bce8401c-e22c-43d8-89
f6-3ec816d32bc8 -Force -Confirm:$false` again searched for the feature but now that was not available. And after giving deploy command from VS the same error occurred..

Comment: See my other answer above?

Answer (score 0):

Try to list out all the timerjobs on the webapp (via PowerShell), if the timerjob is still installed: Uninstall it, and delete it. (from PS)

http://sharepointhangout.com/powershell-script-to-list-timer-jobs-sharepoint-webapplication-get-sptimerjob/

Then try to activate your feature again.